# How to disable Firebase cookies?

Tags: firebase, cookies, privacy

I'm currently running a project that uses Firebase Hosting and Firebase Functions. Both functions apparently use some cookies for their own reasons, but I can't seem to find a way to 'disable' them for my website visitors.

All around, I'm not very well informed on GDPR laws, but I'd like my webpage to comply with those, by giving users the chance to opt out of cookies.

Is there a way to disable those cookies? And if not, is it possible that they are already GDPR compliant?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies used for Firebase are specifically for Authentication reasons only, Firebase doesn't track personal information or data but rather stores a randomized Javascript Web Token to re-authenticate a user when your app gets refreshed or reloaded.

Additional client-side data is used for caching the database to increase read performance but doesn't expose or track a user by any means either.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I do have a question though, apparently hosting my project on Firebase hosting shows _fbp cookies, and around 8 cookies. On further research, _fbp is a Facebook Pixel cookie, is that actually possible or is my browser bugged?

Comment: it's not bugged, but will be residue from auth or any browser apps you may have related to facebook

Comment: I find this hard to believe as firebase also supports analytics. So what is it?

Comment: Analytics are used to send data to the server about crashes, interactions, and developer defined objects from within your app - if you look at the documentation, you will see it is reactionary to your apps state, nothing is natively used to track the user's identity or personal information. 
There are additional fingerprint data that can only be accessed if you upgrade to Big Query. But in general, these are not anything personal or can be identified unless a developer goes out of their way to do so.